# Passing a value by ref to an IENumerator function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

To clarify I'm doing this in Unity3D, which may or may not be important?

I'm trying to figure out if I can pass a value by ref to an IEnumerator function that does not yield.  If I try to do it with one that yields, VS2010 complains ("Iterators cannot have ref or out parameters"), but, if I wrap the call up with a similar IEnumerator function that calls the yielding function, but does not yield itself, the error goes away and things *appear* to work.  I'm trying to find out if I'm in unexpected behavior land or if this is normal behavior.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
IEnumerator Wrapper(ref int value)
{
    int tmp = ++value;    // This is the ONLY place I want the value
    return Foo(tmp);      // of the ref parameter to change!  
}                         // I do _NOT_ want the value of the ref
                          // parameter to change in Foo()!
IENumerator Foo(int value)
{
    // blah blah
    someFunc(value);
    someSlowFunc();
    yield return null;
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Well, don't expect `value` to change after the initial increment.

Comment: I only want it to change when I increment it in Wrapper.  In my code there is a value that needs to be incremented once and only once before the code is called, so I wanted to wrap it up so I wouldn't accidentally forget to do that at some point and introduce hard to trace bugs.  (Updated the question to be a bit clearer in that regard, thanks!)

Comment: Note that you can now very easily ... http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/551381/view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good.  The top function just returns an IEnumerator - but is otherwise a normal function.  The bottom function *is* an IEnumerator [transformed into a funky class by the compiler] and as such cannot have a ref value.

The top function could have been written as such:

```
 void Wrapper(ref int value, out IEnumerator coroutine)
 {
     int tmp = ++value;
     coroutine = Foo(tmp);
 }
```

This is a little more messy - but it shows how this is a *normal* function that deals with two pieces of data.  A int passed by referance, and a IEnumerator [just a class] that it returns [in this example by using out].

---

Supplemental:  This is how stuff works behind the scenes:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Lets get the 'IEnumerable Class' that RandomNum gets compiled down into.
        var IEnumeratorClass = RandomNum(10, 10);

        //All an IEnumerable is is a class with 'GetEnumerator'... so lets get it!
        var IEnumerableClass = IEnumeratorClass.GetEnumerator();

        //It can be used like so:
        while (IEnumerableClass.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IEnumerableClass.Current);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 10));

        //Of course, that's a lot of code for a simple job.
        //Luckily - there's some nice built in functionality to make use of this.
        //This is the same as above, but much shorter
        foreach (var random in RandomNum(10, 10)) Console.WriteLine(random);

        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 10));

        //These simple concepts are behind Unity3D coroutines, and Linq [which uses chaining extensively]
        Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Take(5).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static IEnumerable<int> RandomNum(int max, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return rnd.Next(i);
    }

    //This is an example of what the compiler generates for RandomNum, see how boring it is?
    public class RandomNumIEnumerableCompiled : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        int max, count;
        Random _rnd;
        public RandomNumIEnumerableCompiled(int max, int count)
        {
            this.max = max;
            this.count = count;
            _rnd = rnd;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new RandomNumIEnumeratorCompiled(max, count, rnd);
        }

        IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new RandomNumIEnumeratorCompiled(max, count, rnd);
        }

    }
    public class RandomNumIEnumeratorCompiled : IEnumerator<int>
    {
        int max, count;
        Random _rnd;
        int current;
        int currentCount = 0;
        public RandomNumIEnumeratorCompiled(int max, int count, Random rnd)
        {
            this.max = max;
            this.count = count;
            _rnd = rnd;
        }

        int IEnumerator<int>.Current { get { return current; } }

        object IEnumerator.Current { get { return current; } }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (currentCount < count)
            {
                currentCount++;
                current = rnd.Next(max);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void Reset() { currentCount = 0; }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
```

Comment: In my real code I'm doing network level loading, and I can supply a prefix-value for all networkview objects, which should be incremented every time a new level is loaded.  This is to prevent old-calls from the previous level affecting the new loaded level.  This should happen _every_ time this Foo() function is called, and to would introduce hard to track bugs if I do not do it.  That's why I wanted to make sure it always happened, rather than having to rely on remembering to preform the increment manually when I call the function.

Comment: Also, thanks for the answer.  It makes sense now (I was reading more on what IEnumerator functions were, but I wasn't really certain on how it worked until I read your answer, so, thanks!)

Comment: Hehehe, sounds good :)  Just made a small edit to help clarify what's going on. IEnumerator's [and IEnumerable's] are a little confusing because of the background magic, but are very useful once you know how they work :)

Comment: One final thing: this is irrelevant but maybe someone will find it useful, in unity3d you cannot start coroutine functions by calling them in certain built-in functions (such as Start() and FixedUpdate()) - so you have to use their function "StartCoroutine()" - which, requires the wrapper function to return an IEnumerator.  That's probably what caused a lot of my confusion in the first place!

Comment: I'm a Unity dev - so I understand.  What you're seeing there is not to do with unity - An IEnumerator simply returns an IEnumerator.  Just in the same way a function of type List<> just returns a List<> - albiet the compiler will 'automagically' create the IEnumerator class for you in the former case.  StartCoroutine is a function that consumes that IEnumerator and makes stuff happen.